# Change string in multiple files using sed

Tags: string, bash, sed, filenames

I have multiple files like this:

> 67 572
>   Cy_aJATC23  ?????????????????????????GCCCTGCTGAGGCCCATAGTCACAGAAGGACAAAGTGCCAGACCACCCCCTTTCTGGCCTTTAATCTGTGGTGGTGCTGGCACTGCCTCCACACGGGCCTCACTGTGTGACAATGCTCCTTTCAGGTGAGGTCTGATCGGGACAAGTTCACAATCATGCTGGATGTAAAACACTTCTCTCCCGAAGACTTGAGTGTGAAGATTATTGATGACTTTGTGGAAATCCATGGCAAGCACAGTGAAAGGCAGGTAAGTGGAAGTGATGGTGATGGTGGAGAAACTGGAGAGTCCAGCTCCGTTTCCCTTCTTTCCAACGGTTCTCAGCTGAAGGAAAAAAAAAAAGAATATATCAGAAGAAGGAGTTAATTATGAATTGTCATTATTGGCACGGCCTGTTCCCATAGAGCCCCCATCTGATATCTGACAATAACAA

I want  change the first line

> 65 572

by

> ['name of the file' 572]

the name of the file is 'ACA_exon2.phylip-sequential' and I just want the first part 'ACA_exon2' but I'm ok with all, I can change it after.

I'm very close with this

`for file in ~/folder/*; do sed -E 's/^ (\w+)( \w+)/\[$file\2]/g' $file ; done;`

This is the result

> [$file 572]
>   Cy_aJATC23  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????TACCACCCAAGATGTTAACAAGCTGGCATGTTTTGAGCATCAAAGATAGAGAGGAAACTGTGTTTACATGTTTGGCACAAAAACTAATGAGGAAAGTCAATTGGCCCTTTGTCTTGAGGGTCTGAAGAGCCGCGCTCTAATGTTTGGTTTCTTGGTTGGCACTTGTTCAAGTAATCACTCGTGGCCTGACAAAGCAGCACTTGTGTTTTATTAGTGGCCATGCTGAACTCTCCTGCCTGGGCTATGTTGCCTCTCAATAGAGCACTGCACCAGAGGGCATACTTATTTGAAAACACTAAATCAGAGCATGATGATCTTTGCCCGACAAATACAACCAAGAGAGGAGAAAGAAAAGTGACAACAGCTCTCCTTTTGTTAGAGAAAGTGAGGAAACAACAACTGGTGTGTGTGCATGTGCATGTGTGTAAGATGAGTCCTGAAACACCGGTGACGAAATGAGCAAAACTTTGTTCCCATAATGTGATGCTCAGAACCAACTGGATT???

sed does not recognize the $file as command to keep the name in the text...

I want this

> [ACA_exon2 572]
>   Cy_aJATC23  ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????TACCACCCAAGATGTTAACAAGCTGGCATGTTTTGAGCATCAAAGATAGAGAGGAAACTGTGTTTACATGTTTGGCACAAAAACTAATGAGGAAAGTCAATTGGCCCTTTGTCTTGAGGGTCTGAAGAGCCGCGCTCTAATGTTTGGTTTCTTGGTTGGCACTTGTTCAAGTAATCACTCGTGGCCTGACAAAGCAGCACTTGTGTTTTATTAGTGGCCATGCTGAACTCTCCTGCCTGGGCTATGTTGCCTCTCAATAGAGCACTGCACCAGAGGGCATACTTATTTGAAAACACTAAATCAGAGCATGATGATCTTTGCCCGACAAATACAACCAAGAGAGGAGAAAGAAAAGTGACAACAGCTCTCCTTTTGTTAGAGAAAGTGAGGAAACAACAACTGGTGTGTGTGCATGTGCATGTGTGTAAGATGAGTCCTGAAACACCGGTGACGAAATGAGCAAAACTTTGTTCCCATAATGTGATGCTCAGAACCAACTGGATT???

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be *way* easier to do in `awk`

Comment: Be sure to use quotes around your variable expansions in Bash btw. `"$file"` in your example above...

Comment: It not works with `"$file"` - `["$file" 572]`

Comment: I can see that it won't work. Just pointing out that variables need to be quoted in Bash or bad things may happen. See my answer to see what is quoted and what is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat f1.exon
67 572 Cy_aJATC23 ?????????????????????????
GCCCTGCTGAGGCCCATAGTCACAGAAGGACAAAGTGCCAGACCACCCCCTTTCTGGCCTT
$ cat f2.exon
67 573 Cy_aJATC23 ?????????????????????????
GCCCTGCTGAGGCCCATAGTCACAGAAGGACAAAGTGCCAGACCACCCCCTTTCTGGCCTT
```

You can do this in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{$1="[" FILENAME; $2=$2 "]"} 1' *.exon
[f1.exon 572] Cy_aJATC23 ?????????????????????????
GCCCTGCTGAGGCCCATAGTCACAGAAGGACAAAGTGCCAGACCACCCCCTTTCTGGCCTT
[f2.exon 573] Cy_aJATC23 ?????????????????????????
GCCCTGCTGAGGCCCATAGTCACAGAAGGACAAAGTGCCAGACCACCCCCTTTCTGGCCTT
```

Same concept in `sed`:

```
for fn in *.exon; do 
    sed -E '1s/^[[:digit:]]+( [[:digit:]]+)/['"$fn"'\1]/' "$fn"
done    
# same output
```

---

*How can I save it in the files?*

You can redirect the files to a temp file and then `mv` the temp file rename the original file that new content:

```
for fn in *.exon; do 
    awk 'FNR==1{$1="[" FILENAME; $2=$2 "]"} 1' "$fn" > a_temp_exon
    mv a_temp_exon "$fn"
done
```

With `sed` just use the `-i` inplace replacement option.

Explanation:

```
awk 'FNR==1{$1="[" FILENAME; $2=$2 "]"} 1' *.exon
      ^   ^                                       first line only
           ^                          ^           do this action
            ^                                     first field
               ^     ^                            literal [ and FILENAME
                             ^                    second field
                                 ^                it's same value
                                    ^             literal ]
                                        ^         print the line
```

Comment: Nice, it works fine. How can I save it in the files? Also, do you know how to keep only f1 and f2 (your example)? And, can you explain your command, please?

Comment: *Also, do you know how to keep only f1 and f2 (your example)?* I don't understand that part of your question...

Comment: Thank you @dawg! instead of `f1.exon`, just `f1`

Comment: That is just because of the demo filename I used. If your actual filename in `f1` that is what would be used. If your actual file name is `f1.ext` and you only want to insert `f1` you would either use bash parameter expansion or a regex to remove it.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'm just wondering if I could do it just in the command that you gave. But is perfect! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You try to use singular quotes, so, variable inside them will not be expanded.
Try this:

```
sed -E "s/^ (\w+)( \w+)/\[$file\2]/g" $file
```

or

```
sed -E 's/^ (\w+)( \w+)/\['$file'\2]/g' $file
```

Comment: Nope, sed doesn't accept: 'sed: $ for file in ~/folder/*; do sed -E "s/^ (\w+)( \w+)/\[$file\2]/g" $file ; done;
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Nope, same error, and with double it prints ["$file" 572]

Comment: Can you show me how exactly you use double quotes? I mean to get ["$file" 572]

Comment: `for file in ~/folder/*; do sed -E 's/^ (\w+)( \w+)/\["$file"\2]/g' $file ; done;`

Comment: In this case you still use outer singular quotes, and variables will not be expanded

Answer (score 0):

Maxim is right about the variable expansion however I believe you will need to escape the backslashes when using double quotes:

```
sed -E "s/^ (\\w+)( \\w+)/\\[$file\\2]/g" $file
```

Comment: @luke, you are right, we'll need to double slashes when we use double quotes for the whole string